# How to get user uid from firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, firebase-authentication

I need to get user uid from firestore with onSnapshot if i make it manually its work
otherwise its not work, I'm using next.js framework.

**This when i send uid to firestore before i fetch him.**

```
const getData = async () => {
await setDoc(doc(db, 'data', user.uid), {
name: 'T-shirt',
descrption: 'nice t-shirt for winter',
price: 300,
});
};
```

**And this when i fetch it with onSnapshot to get the user uid and data.**

```
useEffect(() => {
onSnapshot(doc(db, 'data', user?.uid), (doc) => {
setItems(doc.data());
console.log(doc.data());
});
}, [user]);
```

**And this is the error he give me.**

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')
```

Comment: Unless you're writing user's `uid`s to your Firestore database, I think you need to rely on `auth` for that, rather than `firestore`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider checking out the following project and how the AuthProvider.jsx component leverages Firebase Authentication to get the user and its current ID, then fetches the "user profile" document from Firestore:

https://github.com/gregfenton/react-and-user-profiles-with-firebase-auth-and-firestore